# Drivehandler: Modify: Is it possible to keep the `GET` request same as default, but only modify the `POST `

Tags: gramex

Keeping default config from help document we have

```yaml
url:
  drivehandler:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/drive
    handler: DriveHandler
    kwargs:
      path: $YAMLURL/drive
      modify: mymodule.modify(handler)
```

`mymodule.py` is created as:

```py
def modify():
    if handler.request.method.upper() == "POST":
        import pandas as pd
        data = []
        for d in pd.DataFrame(handler.files).itertuples():
            print("preprocesed data", d)
```

And gramex server is ran in the default port,
`POST` works great and on the browser console we get the output of the print statement.
However, when we try to `GET` `localhost:9988/drive`; Although the drive/.meta.db is populated, the result is always blank.
So wondering if I modify the `POST` request, Do I need to create a custom modification to `GET` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a GET method, this function returns `None`. Instead, you could use:

```py
def modify(handler, data):
    if handler.request.method.upper() == "POST":
        import pandas as pd

        data = []
        for d in pd.DataFrame(handler.files).itertuples():
            print("preprocesed data", d)
    else:
        return data
```

You would also need to modify `gramex.yaml` to reflect the `data` argument:

```yaml
      modify: mymodule.modify(handler, data)
```

Comment: data is not defined here. Editing the question to include these details.